A monic in a balanced category that is not split?
In a balanced category, epic monics are isomorphisms, and thus split.
I am looking for a balanced category and a monic (or an epic) in it that is not a split monic (respectively epic).

The category of abelian groups is balanced.  In this category, the morphism $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}, n \mapsto 2n$ is monic but not split monic.  Similarly, the projection morphism $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}, n \mapsto n + 2 \mathbb{Z}$ is epic but not split epic.

Brilliant! And the short reasons for these, respectively, are that $1/2\notin\mathbb Z$ and that no nonzero in $\mathbb Z$, when doubled yields $0$.

The category of sets is balanced, and for any nonempty set $X$, the unique function $0 \to X$ is monic but not split.
